# Looking for advice on a mood board

Tags: workflow, design-process, art, abstract, photomontage

Just wondering if somebody could give me opinions/input into a problem i am having. For a college brief I was required to visually record my journey to work over a period of 2 weeks, then narrow in on a particular concept.

The aim of the project will be to document how closely the glamourous and gritty sides of my hometowns city center live side by side. this was born from a huge housing crisis, drug problems and petty crime issues in my city. The evidence of this just happens to be particularly obvious on the path I travel.

So, my next task is to create a moodboard for a final piece, I am struggling.

I should say, this is not a digital project. I can use pretty much anything to create the final piece with the exception of photography and computers.

Things I have in mind include:

Wealth, Poverty, Glamour, business, Struggle, Addiction, Crime, Overcrowding, Claustrophobia.

So I am wondering if anyone has any input on what could represent some of these things in terms of imagery(photography is allowed for mood board), textiles etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is idea gathering and brainstorming and not a good question for the site. Questions need to have *definitive* answers whenever possible. There's no way you could select a "correct" answer if all answers are merely opinions and ideas.

Comment: Agreed, sorry im new to the forum, dont want to go against the traffic. Could u suggest a better tag?

Comment: It's not about the tags, Ximen. You could use any tag and it won't improve the question. It's just not a good question for StackExchange sites. Anything asking for "opinions" or "ideas" is generally off topic. Stack Exchange sites are about Questions and Answers. They aren't really a place for discussion or just general brainstorming.

Comment: I see, sorry again, I will delete the question in that case. Could you suggest a good brainstoming/Idea generation forum, I have tried myself with no success.

Comment: I think the question is interesting and related to brainstorming in graphic design. Graphic design isn't only about using Photoshop and digital montages. The question could be refined in something like "how to get started with the brainstorming for Graphic Design?" or "What are some good tricks to gather data before starting a creative project?". The answers can be useful for logos, flyers, books, special packaging, etc. Brainstorming in graphic design is as appropriate as client relationships, freelance or "I didn't get paid" or "can I use this font"; all questions accepted here.

Comment: @go-meek agreed but this question is not scoped that way.

Comment: @joojaa I noticed. That's why my previous comment said "The question could be refined in something like".... Ximen can always choose to change a few words and edit the question to make it "within scope" if he/she wants to. Just specifying in case my comment wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @Ximen hi, I think we can reopen your question if you [edit] it to focus on a single topic and also provide at least some examples you're considering. Take a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19649/how-to-graphically-represent-time and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1132/how-would-you-represent-religion-in-an-icon-neutrally for examples. Pick your topics on your own and then the ones you're really really struggling with can be asked about individually. Upvoted in the hopes you will [edit] it.